# How to do linear regression with Matrix?

Tags: r

i have a problem doing the linear regression with three Matrix objects.

```
m1 = matrix(c(1:10))
m2 = matrix(c(10:19))
m3 = matrix(c(100:109))
```

I DO NOT have problem if i do:

```
mod = lm(m1+m2 ~ m3+0)
```

I have the problem if i only use TWO Matrixs, like:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1:20), ncol=2)
m2 = matrix(c(1:10))

mod = lm(m1 ~ m2+0)
```

in this case i get TWO coefficients for **m2**:

```
Coefficients:
    [,1]   [,2] 
m2  1.000  2.429
```

but I do not want it I would like that the two columns of the **m1** matrix will be as the previous example (like two distinct columns)

How to do it?

Comment: @Spacedman I would like to do THE same thing as the first example but using ONE matrix that has more that ONE column

Comment: Explain what you want to model, not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I've just realised your bigger matrix is on the LHS, which means its the response, not the covariates. R is fitting 2 models, treating each column separately. The coeffs from lm(m1~m2) are the ones from lm(m1[,1]~m2) and lm(m1[,2]~m2). In your first example you are only fitting a single column matrix on the LHS - m1+m2 ADDS the matrices on the LHS of a formula).

Comment: @Hansi In the first example I "sum" to vectors now i have the matrix, i would like to sum the two columns like i have done with the matrix with one column I would like to do: m1[,1] + m1[,2] but i would like to do it automatically, without writing + + + because I have ONE matrix with many columns. How can i do it?

Comment: @Spacedman please take a look at the comment above for Hansi.

Comment: How about lm(apply(m1,2,sum)~m2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are summing your two column vectors row-wise together and using that as the target. For the matrix m1 I think you want the rowsums as the predictor.

like:

> m1 = matrix(c(1:2000), ncol=200)
>
> m2 = matrix(c(1:10))
>
> msum=apply(m1,1,sum)

now use msum for your response.

> mod = lm(msum ~ m2+0)

This gives just one coeficient. I think this is what you want, but I am still not sure *why* you would want this?